# JodaTime PeriodFormatter, round to get inexact time strings (e.g. "about 3 hours")?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

This is my period formatter

```
PeriodFormatter humanFormat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPrefix("about ")
            .appendHours()
            .appendSuffix(" hrs")
            .toFormatter()
            .withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
```

But when I pass it a period like 5 hrs, 59 minutes this formatter prints "about 5 hours", is there a way to make it round the period to the nearest hour (5:59 -> about 6 hrs, 5:29 -> about 5 hrs)?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you will need to modify your period before calling periodFormatter. You can try something like `if(period.getMinutes() > 30){period = period.plusHours(1);}`

Comment: Thanks, but I think you mean if(period.getMinutes() < 30){period = period.plusHours(-1);}

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to round hours in `PeriodFormatter`.
I can propose you to create separate method that will convert `Period` to `String`, e.g.

```
   static String PERIOD_FORMAT = "about %s hrs";
   static String formatPeriod(Period p)
   {
      int hours = p.getHours();
      hours = p.getMinutes() < 30 ? hours : hours + 1;
      return String.format(PERIOD_FORMAT, hours); 
      //or 'return "about " + hours + " hrs"' - this solution is faster
   }
```